# T-SQL Set (assign) Function Result in SELECT

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to know how to set a RETURN value from a function so it can be used again in the same query.

The problem:

```
SELECT
A.Field1, 
A.Field2,
[TheFunction](ID,3.4,'test') SumOfAverages,
[TheFunction2]([TheFunction](ID,3.4,'test'), 1,2)) Summary
FROM ...
```

You can see I am putting in the function again in Function2 as a parameter, however I would like to Set this into a variable so I do not need to do this.

I have tried doing

```
[TheFunction](ID,3.4,'test') SumOfAverages,
[TheFunction2](SumOfAverages, 1,2)) Summary
```

I don't mind doing this in an outer SELECT but I do not want to JOIN on to the INNER select as I have the fields already to acquire the results.

I would appreciate any help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by shifting the first function into a separate `SELECT` clause. Typical ways to achieve that are to use a CTE, a subquery, or `APPLY`. Something like:

```
SELECT
A.Field1, 
A.Field2,
t.SumOfAverages,
[TheFunction2](t.SumOfAverages, 1,2)) Summary
FROM <existing tables>
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TheFunction(ID,3.4,'test') as SumOfAverages) t
```

The reason for this is that within each `SELECT` clause, the system is meant to be able to evaluate all column expressions in parallel - so the language prohibits any dependencies between the expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to re-use the value, you need to use a subquery or CTE:

```
SELECT t.*,
       [TheFunction2](SumOfAverages, 1,2)) Summary
FROM (SELECT A.Field1, A.Field2,
             [TheFunction](ID,3.4,'test') SumOfAverages,
      FROM ...
     ) t
```